# Как открыть carbon fields для wp rest api?

Tags: wordpress, rest

Читал документацию, написано супер непонятно. На ютубе видео нет. пишет так: Fields can be exposed in WordPress' REST API by using their set_visible_in_rest_api() method:

```
Field::make(...)->set_visible_in_rest_api( $visible = true )
```

вроде вставил, вроде запрос идет, но откуда его братЬ, как брать, непонятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов скачать к примеру скачать плагин [REST API Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-custom-fields/) **(давно не обновлялся**)

В настройке плагина находишь кастомные поля ставишь галочку дальше
названия сайта/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/ид-страницы